# checking session in servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

In my web application i neet to check session already exist or not.

i want to check this in my servlet and in jsp also.

is there any way to check this.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can test it with [`HttpServletRequest#getSession(boolean create)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29) with `create=false`. It will return null if not created yet.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null) {
    // Session is not created.
} else {
    // Session is already created.
}
```

If you actually want to create the session anyway if it doesn't exist, then just grab it and test the freshness using [`HttpSession#isNew()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#isNew%28%29):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.isNew()) {
    // Session is freshly created during this request.
} else {
    // Session was already created during a previous request.
}
```

That was how you would do it in a Servlet. In a JSP you can only test the freshness with help of JSTL and EL. You can grab the session by [`PageContext#getSession()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getSession%28%29) and then just call `isNew()` on it.

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.session.new}">
    <p>Session is freshly created during this request.</p>
</c:if>
```

or

```
<p>Session is ${pageContext.session.new ? 'freshly' : 'already'} created.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to set a session id in the jsp and then check the same session id in the other jsp or servlet to check if it is alive or not.

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.getId();
```